# Swap elements in a multidimensional array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a multidimensional array which contains coordinates extracted from a back-end call, this is a screenshot of the structure:

[image]

I would like to swap those coordinates but I cannot know how to handle that. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] which can be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue.  Note that such an example should be in text form and not only as an image, as described in [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to accomplish what you're looking for.  One approach is to loop through the structure until you reach the arrays you want to manipulate.  In the snippet, I decided to make a function that took the original data and returns a new object.  To 'swap' the contents of the arrays, I did a .splice(0) to make a copy of the array, then called .reverse() on it to switch the order.

The main challenge is working through the data structure - some fairly intuitive levels to the current structure you have (a coordinates object that contains a node called coordinates that is array - just a little confusing)

```js
var dataFromTheServer = {
    content: [
        {
            coordinates: {
                coordinates: [
                    [17.25756,31.19192],
                    [15.1821, 40.87555],
                    [33.78433, 18.59314],
                    [17.25756,31.19192]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

function swapEm(data){
  var response = {};
  if(data && data.content){
      response.content = [{coordinates:{coordinates:[]}}];
      for(var item in data.content){
        if(data.content[item] && data.content[item].coordinates && data.content[item].coordinates.coordinates){
            for(var coord in data.content[item].coordinates.coordinates){
                response.content[0].coordinates.coordinates[coord] = data.content[item].coordinates.coordinates[coord].splice(0).reverse()
            }
        }
      }
  }
  
  return response;
}

console.log(dataFromTheServer);
console.log(swapEm(dataFromTheServer))
```